# Where is the old php.net website?

Tags: php

I know that the new `php.net` website has been released for some time. The old one had the `source code` link in the footer, which allowed a user to see the `php code` of the current webpage. It was very handy. Is there any way to see the `old php.net` website?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding wally

Comment: No offense, but without `giorgio`, `halfer`, `oezi`, `N.B`. and `Nanne` this world would be a better place. You just downvoted without poiting me into the right direction. Nice job! This world is full of guys like you.

Comment: I only voted to close, but you just made me downvote it. Hail to the world! (no offense taken btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to see the updated manual with the old layout, but it is possible to see the old website version on archive.org: http://goo.gl/K7EkSe (Sorry for the shortened url, but the editor didn't allow me to write the url properly)

Comment: Apparently there is not copy of urls like `www.php.net/source.php?url=/credits.php‎`.

Comment: You are right. Looking into archive.org for it (http://goo.gl/rnRSQY) it tells the reason why: "Page cannot be crawled or displayed due to robots.txt.".
Due to robots.txt limitation I think this page's versions will be hardly found somewhere else.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing that out!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [wayback machine](http://archive.org/web/) This allow you to view history of the php website.